# I can not get the latitude & longtitude by GPS in my emulator

Tags: android, gps, location

I have defined a method to get current location by press a button,when i press it in the first times ,it worked.But then it has nothing return to me.And there is no exception thrown out

```
public class getLoc extends Activity{
private Button btn;
private TextView tv;
private  LocationManager locm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_text);
    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_location);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             locm=(LocationManager) getLoc.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new myLocationListener() );
        }
    });
}
protected void getCurrentLocation(){
    Location loc=locm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println(loc.getLatitude());
    System.out.println(loc.getLongitude());
```

Comment: why you are trying it in emulator ? try on real device.

Comment: the code is ok?i have only one mobile of ZTE_U880.it cast long time to get location.

Comment: yes, code is ok, sorry for late reply

Comment: are you trying in emulator or device ? because in emulator you can not get lat-log. and if you are trying in device then you should be in open place like open ground

Comment: ok.my seat is next to the window.i think is ok.Thanks.

Comment: but sometimes that doesnt work , my seat is also next to window but for lat-long, i need to go outside sometimes.

Comment: heh ,yes.it's not easy for control.By the way ,any mobile is do difficult to get current location.

Comment: what ??? I am not getting you.

Comment: Do you like to watch the NBA ?The heat is fighting with LAC right now.Now is 13:13 in China.

Comment: When my app running in different Mobile,it has differnt plm.

Comment: then that is not the your application's problem it might be a problem of that device, is GPS ,option enabled in that new mobile ?

Comment: I can not make my app adapt to all device well.It's killing me.

Comment: why ?? well I think if you go for down version like 1.6 then your application will be supported for large range

Comment: i always dev app with the version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the map api library and intenet permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

did you mention these permissions ?

Comment: thanks at first .i did add this permissions in manifest file.But i using 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION' instead of 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATUION' becase i need a precise location information.

Answer (score 0):

in the myLocationListener class

you should override  onLocationChanged method

```
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(location.getLatitude());
        System.out.println(location.getLongitude());

    }
```

Comment: yes ,It's not be displayed here.heh .Are you Chinese ,too? I guess it by your name(the accont name)  .

Comment: yes Chinese. eclipse can send gps location information to emulator and if you use real device,maybe you should modify gps.conf file to get gps info quicker, google gps.conf.

Comment: yes.I can get latlng by override the OnLocationChange method ,but not the getCurrentLocation which is defined by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modifying the location in Eclipse before sending it again? If you send the same location multiple times, the emulator will not trigger a location event.

Also you have to enable mock locations on the device (somewhere in the developments options) and the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```